# spring petcare example can not add an appointment

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

checked out source code at https://anonsvn.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petcare/trunk, compile, deploy to tomcat 7 and run OK. But when I sign in using my gmail account and try to add an appointment, the "add" button is not click-able in the add appointment popup. Anyone has the same experience and any suggestions?

Comment: can you check any exception in logs and post it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out this is a bug. seems to be fixed in newer version.